# Editing the time series- decomposed plots

Tags: r, time-series, stl-decomposition, autoplot

Is it possible to remove the empty grey boxes (highlighted inside red circle) present to the right side of the decomposed plots (attached)?

Also, it is possible to change the title fonts (highlighted inside green circle) of the individual to Times New Roman or any other fonds of choice?

The r code used for creating the plot is as below

`autoplot(decompose(x, type = "additive"))+labs(y=expression(Chl[a]~(µg/L)), x="Year") + ggtitle(expression(Decomposed~Chl[a]~Time~Series~BB1)) + theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))`

**time series- decomposed plots**

[image: time series- decomposed plots]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Without the object `x` I cannot easily provide a sample of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the forecast package it is not possible to position the scale bars on the left. You would have to remove the scale bars and add them to the left yourself manually. This can be done by setting `autoplot(x, range.bars = FALSE)`.

You can specify the font family in ggplot2 by setting the appropriate `theme()` text field to `element_text(family = ***)`.

I have used `USAccDeaths` as an example dataset here:

```r
library(fpp2)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp2 2.4 ──
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.5.9000     ✓ fma       2.4       
#> ✓ forecast  8.15           ✓ expsmooth 2.3
#> 
autoplot(decompose(USAccDeaths, type = "additive"))+
  labs(y=expression(Chl[a]~(µg/L)), x="Year") + 
  ggtitle(expression(Decomposed~Chl[a]~Time~Series~BB1)) +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
    text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 15)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! When I executed your revised code, everything worked perfectly. However, when I have incorporated range. bars = FALSE into the same code I end up with an error as below
autoplot(decompose(x, range.bars = FALSE, type = "additive"))+
  labs(y=expression(Chl[a]~(µg/L)), x="Year") + 
  ggtitle(expression(Decomposed~Chl[a]~Time~Series~BB1)) +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
    text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 15)
  )
Error in decompose(x, range.bars = FALSE, type = "additive") : 
  unused argument (range.bars = FALSE)

Comment: `range.bars` is an argument of `autoplot()` not `decompose()`. So your first plotting line should be: `autoplot(decompose(x, type = "additive"), range.bars = FALSE)`